# how to handle update application resource - how to handle monorepo

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I have mono repo -> Kubernetes -> environments -> name_of_env -> apps -> yamls files with Application definitions (kind: Application). So far, I was simply doing kubectl apply -f app_name.yaml. I would like to automate this, that after a commit / push to the repo it automatically does apply.

Is there some mechanism I should use, or do you just use a CI (Gitlab, Circle etc.) that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do with monorepo. By use `path` in `Application` with `Helm` or `Kustomize`

Example with `Kustomize`:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: guestbook
spec:
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: kustomize-guestbook

    kustomize:
      version: v3.5.4
```

Reference: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/kustomize/

Comment: but what If i want to update application after values changes? not whole chart definition?

Comment: Yes. Please config the sync policy https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/auto_sync/. The ArgoCD is interval `180s` check and update change. In case you want reactive action config the webhook of ArgoCD https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/webhook/

Answer (score 0):

[App Of Apps Pattern](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/cluster-bootstrapping/#app-of-apps-pattern) or [ApplicationSet](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/)

App Of Apps Pattern is create a Application definitions (kind: Application) that   contains other application definitions (kind: Application).

ApplicationSet cloud auto create application base on your folder structure.